# My employer could not remember my pay or starting/ending dates...and he's my dad

Tags: background-check

I had an interview for a Sales position with a highly successful company, and they called me the next day to make an offer.  Not surprisingly, and understandably, the offer is contingent upon my passing a background check.  I have no criminal record of any kind; my concern is in relation to my previous employers and the information they have and will provide.

In the past 5 years I have worked for my current employer (3½ years) my current part-time employer (2¼ years) and prior to that I worked for two other companies, ableit briefly, only 1 year for one and 1¼ year for the other.  One of those has an entirely different staff at this point so nobody there even knows me, so I don't know what information they can possibly provide.  The other job I am particularly worried about, and here's why:

One of my employers was my father.  I worked for his company and it was quite unofficial in that I never interviewed for the job and, given my prior experience, performed many managerial functions without being a manager.  I was the only one who had such a role among the three stores that he owned.  I knew I wasn't a manager, but I was not a delivery driver like the other staff.  So, for job title I wrote "supervisor."  As I said this was all pretty unofficial.  I also never saw a pay stub; they went directly to my dad as I was living for him and the money just went to rent and bills.  However, I am sure of my start/end dates (I am great with dates) and pay (he told me when I started what it would be, and believe me, I remember, as it was not in line with the pay I received for my previous job as a manager at another retail establishment).  He told me yesterday that the background check company called and I asked him what was said.  Well, it turns out that he told them I made "like 9 bucks an hour" and that my ending pay was "I don't know, 9.50?"  which is off by $1-$1.50 an hour.  I told them the correct pay which was LESS than what he said. He also could not remember my start and end dates and told them I was a counter salesperson.  I am completely worried that I will fail my check over this!  I know he was just getting annoyed with the person asking the questions; apparently he didn't understand half of what she was saying and became extremely irritated.  I don't know if they will realize, this is my dad's business, it wasn't as black and white as most situations and it is not in the same industry as the job for which I have applied.  I realize this situation is unique but does anyone actually have any experience or knowledge to share?

Comment: Regardless of the outcome of your interview/application process with this other company, both you and your father need to get your records in order. **You** should be in possession of your pay stubs, no one else. Your father should have records of your exact date of hire and pay history. If your father isn't able to accurately answer the questions immediately on the phone, he should be writing those questions down, saying "I'll get back to you by X date", research the questions and then respond by that date. That's part of properly operating a business.

Comment: I second @alroc. You and your dad need to be in sync AND you need to take ownership of the task of making sure that you and your dad are in sync. Much as you love your dad, it's YOUR life that he is screwing up and you are the one who has to make sure that he stops doing it.

Answer (score 8):

Have your dad call back the other person and confirm your dates and your pay. And have him confirm the whole thing in writing if that's necessary. As far as your position title is concerned, explain to him what you did and have him agree with you that you were functioning as a supervisor. Frankly, you need to take care of these loose ends and have your story line and your dad's story line be in sync before the next background check company calls.